# sedコマンド 正規表現 +の扱い

Tags: sed, 正規表現

sed コマンドで以下が動きません。
環境: Mac OS X の Yosemite
目的: `hello` から先を `X` に置き換え、`helloX` を得たい。

```
echo "helloddkkdddd" | sed -e "s/hello.\+/X/g"
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 最初は「hello以下を X に置き換えたい。」で編集で「hello から先を X に置き換え、helloX を得たい。」になってますが、最初ので合っていたのではないでしょうか? GNU sed なら「hello以下は X に置き換わる」になりますし。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

グループ化をつかって以下の様に

```
echo "helloddkkdddd" | sed -e "s/\(hello\).\+/\1X/g"
```

とすれば

```
helloX
```

となります。

簡単な説明としては

`\(...\)`で括られた部分がグループとして扱われ、`\1` を使って最初に登場したグループのマッチ結果を出力することができます。

Answer (score 4):

Macのsedだと+が使えないか、別の表現が必要なようです。

```
$ echo "helloddkkdddd" | gsed -e "s/hello..*/X/g"
X
```

とやるか、brewをお使いでしたら、

```
$ brew install coreutils
```

としてGNUのsed（gsed）をインストールすると+が使えます。

```
$ echo "helloddkkdddd" | gsed -e "s/hello.\+/X/g"
X
```

-r オプションを指定すれば、バックスラッシュでエスケープする必要はありません。

```
$ echo "helloddkkdddd" | gsed -r -e "s/hello.+/X/g"
X
```

出力が

```
$ echo "helloddkkdddd" | sed 
helloxxxxxxxx
```

というものなら、ちょっと悩みますが、とりあえずawkを使うズルを一つ提示しておきます。

```
$ echo "helloddkkdddd" | sed 's/hello\(.*\)/hello \1/' | awk '{gsub(/./,"X",$2);print}' | sed 's/ //'
helloXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: 助かりました。
gsedってあったのですね。

Comment: 役に立ったようでよかったです。

Answer (score 3):

sed で利用できる正規表現は拡張正規表現ではありません。
GNU sed であればバックスラッシュ `\` を前に付与し `\+` のようにすることで拡張正規表現のパターンを書けますが、GNU sed 以外の sed 実装では使えません。

よって、どのような sed でも利用できるコマンドラインは次のようになります:

```
$ echo "helloddkkdddd" | sed -e "s/\(hello\)..*/\1X/g"
```

もしくは繰り返し回数指定の `\{MIN,MAX\}` を利用して次のようになります:

```
$ echo "helloddkkdddd" | sed -e "s/\(hello\).\{1,\}/\1X/g"
```

GNU sed 依存でよければ次のようになります:

```
$ echo "helloddkkdddd" | sed -e "s/\(hello\).\+/\1X/g"
```

Mac OS X や FreeBSDの sed であれば `-E` オプションを付けることで拡張正規表現が使えます。
よって次のようになります。

```
$ echo "helloddkkdddd" | sed -E -e "s/(hello).+/\1X/g"
```

GNU sed も `-r` オプションで直接(`\`なしで)拡張正規表現が使えます。
また、FreeBSD の sed にも GNU sed 互換用の `-r` オプションがあります。
よって、GNU sed もしくは FreeBSD sed では次のように書けます。

```
$ echo "helloddkkdddd" | sed -r -e "s/(hello).+/\1X/g"
```

Comment: `-E` オプションは 2022年後期予定の POSIX Issue 8 で標準化されます。今後は `-E` オプション推奨で、GNU でも BSD でも macOS でも動作します。  https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528

Answer (score 2):

Mac ではなく Linux の文章ですが・・・

- http://linuxjm.sourceforge.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man7/regex.7.html

> 古い ("基本") 正規表現は、いくつかの点において異なる。 '|', '+', and '?' は通常の文字となる。 対応する機能は存在しない。繰り返し指定の区切りは "\{" および "\}" となる。'{' と '}' は、 単独では通常の文字として扱われる。 部分正規表現をネストする括弧は "\(" および "\)" となり、 '(' と ')' は単独では通常の文字となる。 '^' は正規表現の先頭か、 括弧でくくられた部分表現の先頭(!)を除いて通常の文字となる。 '$' は正規表現の末尾か、 括弧でくくられた部分正規表現の末尾(!)を除いて通常の文字となる。 '*' は、正規表現の先頭か、 括弧でくくられた部分文字列の先頭に置かれた場合は通常の文字となる ('^') が前置されていてもよい)。

`|`、`+`、`?` は存在せず、`(`、`)`、`{`、`}` はそのままだと単なる文字として認識されるため `\(`、`\)`、`\{`、`\}` のようなエスケープが必要、とのことです。

たしかに `(` や `)` が正規表現のメタ文字ではなく、単なる文字として解釈されています。

```
$ echo '(())' | sed 's/()/^^/'
(^^)
```